# Any-goal bidirectional A* pathfinding reference

Tags: reference, graph-theory, path-finding, a-star

*(reposted from cs.stackexchange since I got no answers or comments)*

I want to solve the problem of finding a shortest path on a directed weighted graph from a certain node to *any* of a specified set of destination nodes (preferably the closest one, but that's not that important). The standard (I believe) way to do this with the A* algorithm is to use a distance-to-closest-goal heuristic (which is admissable) and exit as soon as any of the goal nodes is reached.

However, in my scenario (which is game AI, if that matters) some (or all) of the goals might be unreachable; furthermore, the set of nodes reachable from such goals is typically quite small (or, at least, I want to optimize in that particular case). For the case of a single goal, bidirectional search sounds promising: the reverse search direction would quickly exhaust all reachable nodes and conclude that no path exists. [These slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/EPP%20shortest%20path%20algorithms.pdf) by Andrew Goldberg et al. describe the bidirectional A* algorithm with proper conditions on the heuristics, as well as stopping conditions.

My question is: is there a way to combine these two approaches, i.e. to perform bidirectional A* to find path to *any* of a specified set of goal nodes? I'm not sure what heuristic function to choose for the reverse search direction, what are the stopping conditions, etc. Googling for anything on this topic didn't get me anywhere either.

Comment: cs is computer science?  Sounds like the correct site for this question.  If you want some responses, place a bounty on your question there.  You likely will not get anything here - this is a coding site.

Comment: @ravenspoint Yes, I know what it is :) It has a much larger audience, though, so I thought I'd give it a try.

Comment: A* works best for path finding if not all of the graph details are 'visible' at the start e,g obstacles become known only if you bump into them while heading for the goal.  If the entire graph is known from the start ( guessing this is your situation ) then the Dijkstra algorithm will work quickly and simply for this problem.